# Is it possible to make a chat bot and use it as a template multiple times in the same platform?

Tags: botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

This is the scenario: We are building a bot, we are planning to use that bot as template for multiple clients. The thing is the bot will share the same logic, entities, actions and answers.

But since we are planning to use the bot multiple times in one channel that means we should create a new bot (new bot secret ID and identification) each time we add a new client. Only will deffer on the branding specific answers like a personalization for each client.

Additional the other challenge is since the bot does not have any "context" of the page he is talking e.g "Client 1 FB" vs "Client 2 SKype". How can we add branding customization to the bot?

#### About MS bot framework

Our first approach was to use MS bot framework, and here you can have a unique session for each user that interacts with the bot. Bot how to have like a unique brand through the channel were the bot is deployed?

- There some other bot framework alternative that can make the following:
  Have multiple instances of the bot in the same channel: Eg. Facebook Messenger
- Without duplicate the source code repository: E.g Github and avoid multiple instances of the bot.

Will appreciate any advice or bot framework.

Comment: The real solution here is to deploy multiple bots.  Why is there an aversion to this, what is your use case, why are you trying to avoid this?